# Test for all player without a score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to run a command for `@a` that *doesn't* have a score of 1. Is there a way to do that? (0 wont work because the default is no score, not 0). I would list my command but I'm not sure of the format. I want it to set all players without a score of 1 to `/gamemode` Survival. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly target somebody that has no score instantiated.

If you absolutely need to avoid any score except 1 (i.e. a score of 0 or lower, 2 or higher, or no score at all), you can label players that have a score of 1 and then target players without that label:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[score_OBJ_min=1,score_OBJ=1,tag=!one] add one
/gamemode survival @a[tag=!one]
/scoreboard players set @a[tag=!one] OBJ 1
```

The benefit here is that no commands here are constantly running, as players that did match will no longer do so.

---

An alternative is to add 0 to their score in order to instantiate it with a default of 0, which will not change their score if they're already tracked:

```
/scoreboard players add @a OBJ 0
/gamemode survival @a[score_OBJ=0]
/scoreboard players set @a[score_OBJ=0] OBJ 1
```

The first `/scoreboard` command is always running, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.13, the `/execute unless score` command can now target players that don't have a score instantiated. The trick is to find a condition that seems to always be true; it'll fail only when a score is not present:

```
execute as @a unless score @s objective = @s objective run …
```